# Logic for adding number whenever the condition is true

Tags: javascript, logic

I have a function in real time. It is for a chat. So, whenever a new message arrives I want to count the number. What I have done is:

```
  onNewMessage: message => {
      const isCheck   =  message.sender.id === '{{Auth::user()->name}}{{Auth::id()}}'
      const count = message.roomId === v.id;
      var i = 0;
      if(count == true) {
          $('.badge-color.'+message.senderId).html('');
          b = i+1;
          console.log(`This is new ${b}`);
          i = b;
          $('.badge-color.'+message.senderId).append(b);
      }
      console.log(`This is new ${i}`);
      console.log(`Outside : ${i}`);
 }
```

I took a variable i and equated it to 0. Then everytime a message arrives, I want to add it. So, I am taking b as the result and equating i = b, so that the next time a message arrives i = 1 and not 0, so it will give b as 2 and so on. But it is not working, it is giving 1 constantly.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Where's the `function`? How/when is it called? What's `count` and how is it declared and changed?

Comment: Updated in the question.

Comment: You've declared `i` inside that function. Every time the function is called `i` will be re-initialized to zero.

Comment: Each time on new message i is set to 0, that's why you are getting 1. Change the scope of i.

Answer (score 0):

The code looks valid I'd say. Is that the real code, or are you storing them in objects?

Try to use b = ++i and please tell me, if it'll work.

//edit after your edit:

nvm, your i is created when you receive a message. A hotfix is to use a global i, but I'd not recommend using global variables. You could store it in a object, like:

```
//init object:
let obj = { counter: 0 };


//incrementing it when you have to:
obj.counter++;
```

//edit:

The thing is, you also could initialize the variable globally, but it wouldn't be that different from method one. But instead, you can store it in some uservariable. I don't know what that Auth::user() service is, but maybe you can store it in: Auth::user()->counter  (set this to 0 when it is first being initialized or loaded from your database, and count it up whenever you receive a message)

Comment: I am adding it into my code, but it is showing syntax error. Can you add in the code, so that I can see if I am doing it correctly or not?

Comment: Hey @TehEbil, the other thing worked, but i would like to know your way as well.

Comment: @Rob sorry for not responding fast. I edited my answer, hope, it helps.